# Is there a way to make a discord.js bot on startup send a message to a certain text channel?

Tags: discord.js

I wanna know if there is a way to make a discord.js bot send a message on startup to a certain text channel.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is possible by using the ready event.
Any code here will be executed when the bot is ready"

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    client.channels.cache.get("channel-id-here")
          .send(`I'm online!`)
})
```